# Obj-c, If I'm using getters and setters for a selection screen pushed into navigation, where do I get my value back, viewWillAppear?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using getters and setters on a selection screen, which is pushed onto the navigation stack, by a button on my navigation bar.

The selection screen sets the variables, however I'm not sure where to get the value on my parent screen.

The selection screen is only initiated and defined in my navigation bar button.

Do I have to declare the viewController in my interface of my parent screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MANY ways to do this, and over the time I've been working on iPhone software I've experimented with most of them. Here's one.

In your child view controller, you can make a property that is a pointer to the parent view controller. Thusly:

ChildViewController.h

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController
{
    ParentViewController *parentViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ParentViewController *parentViewController;
```

ChildViewController.m

```
@implementation ChildViewController

@synthesize parentViewController;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [parentViewController release];
}
```

When you do the work to instantiate the child and push it onto the nav controller, you can set any variables you want on that child's properties, including setting, say:

```
ChildViewController *child = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"nibName" withBundle:nil];
child.parentViewController = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:child animated:YES];
[child release];
```

Then inside the child, you can talk about properties of the parent directly, as they get set by the user in the fields of the child, so...

```
self.parentViewController.dataField = @"My data for an NSString property of the parent view controller!";
```

Then when you pop the child back off, you'll find that you actually set that data into the `.dataField` property of the parent view controller.

(All code in this answer was typed right in here and is intended as an example only--I make no promises about spelling, syntax, etc. )

Comment: but beware of circular references: parent retains child and child retains parent. You'll need extra precautions to break the loop, otherwise you'll get nasty leaks.

Comment: We're using a UINavigationController here, though, which will release the child when it pops it. And ParentViewController releases the child when it pushes it on the nav stack. So there's no circularity in this instance--though it's true that the most general application of this approach certainly could be prone to it. Just to be clear about that, I added the release on push to my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController gives you access to the navigation stack, check the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can there find your parent view in the navigation history and then it should be easy to access its properties.

To find it, the UINavigationController has a method as described above:

> viewControllers
>
> The view controllers currently on the navigation stack.
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
> Discussion
>
> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index > n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

In short: your parent view controller is at `n-2`.

Comment: so where do I access the parameters once the view hands back to the parent view, viewWillApear ?

Comment: Ah, okay - you want to pass back informtion from the child view? So: find the parent view in the UINavigationController and set appropriate properties - in viewWillDisappear

Comment: I added more information how to find the parent view controller in the solution text above (more readable).